# Get the first few characters without the extension of the file in DOS

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, ms-dos, echo

My files are AAAAAAA-01.pdf , BBBBBB-02.pdf, CCCCCCC-03.pdf
I was able to generate an excel list of file name in the folder without the extension using this command below:

```
for %%i in (*.pdf) do @echo %%~ni >> C:\LIST.xls
```

How do I have it get the first 7 characters of the file?
I want the out put list of just AAAAAA , BBBBBBB, CCCCCCC , ...

My second questions is: How do I only get those characters before the DASH - ?
For example my files are ABCD-01.pdf , A-03.pdf, AB-00.pdf, ...
I want the output to be ABCD , A, AB, ...

I found this `set first7=%%I:~0,7%` but don't know how to get it to work.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You can always import the whole name into Excel then convert the data using excel formulas. That is almost always my pref.  Example: import your list to column A, make column B something like `=LEFT(A1,7)` and copy it down the column, then hide Column A

Comment: I am running this in a BATCH FILE and schedule it to run multiple times a day. I have other excel file pull data from this output list using vlookup. I don't want to open the output list and have it generate 7 characters everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if exist List.xls del List.xls
for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
    set fn=%%~na
    set fn=!fn:~0,7!
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=-" %%f in ('echo !fn!') do echo %%f>>List.xls
)
```

This will print the first 7 letters of each file name. However if there's a hyphen present then it will further truncate and print only the letters before the hyphen.

Comment: He he, my answer is shorter than yours - effectively a one liner ;)

Comment: The second part of my answer prints only the letters before the hyphen however many there are (in one `for /f` statement). You don't need to extract the 7 letters first.

Comment: Unhh... What if the hyphen's present after the 8th letter? Won't you end up with 8 letters then? My batch file takes care of both his requirements in one go. Hope that's clear now?

Comment: OK. You win ;) I read his (a little unclear) question as two kind of unrelated parts ...

Comment: @Karan thank you for your answer. I just tried it. It created 2 spaces and the end of the file name. Do you know how to remove those 2 blank spaces?. Also, everytime I ran the batch file, the list add on to the previous list. Is there a way to overwrite the old list?

Comment: @Chaunghian: Kindly let me know the original file names and the corresponding strings that the batch file printed, because I'm not able to figure out where it's printing these 2 spaces you speak of. To overwrite the old list is simple. Just use `echo %%f>List.txt` instead of `echo %%f>>List.txt`. A single `>` overwrites the file whereas `>>` appends to the file instead.

Comment: @Karan I tried it like this `echo !_name:~0,7!>c:\list.xls` . It overwrited the file. However, only 1 file name appear in the list now. This one, with the space at the end "T3L954- " . The original file names are K14O211-02.pdf, R14L211-03.pdf, T3L954-56.pdf, S3L054-41.pdf

Comment: @Chaunghian: Try the modified batch file above.

Comment: @Chaunghian: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I have it get the first 7 characters of the file?

> I want the out put list of just AAAAAA , BBBBBBB, CCCCCCC , ...

Use the following batch file (to extract the first 7 letters of the filename).

test.cmd:

```
@echo off
@Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%i in (*.pdf) do (
  set _name=%%~ni
  echo !_name:~0,7!>> c:\list.xls
  )
```

example output:

```
C:\test>dir *.pdf
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is C8D0-DF1E

 Directory of C:\test

19/06/2015  17:56                 0 AAAAAAA-01.pdf
19/06/2015  17:56                 0 BBBBBBB-02.pdf
19/06/2015  17:57                 0 CCCCCCC-03.pdf
               3 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  92,871,524,352 bytes free

C:\test>test

C:\test>type c:\list.xls
AAAAAAA
BBBBBBB
CCCCCCC

C:\test>
```

#### How do I only get those characters before the DASH - ?

> For example my files are ABCD-01.pdf , A-03.pdf, AB-00.pdf, ... I want the output to be ABCD , A, AB, ...

Use the following batch file (to extract all of the letters before a `-`)

test.cmd:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=-" %%i in (`dir /b *.pdf`) do echo %%i>> c:\list.xls
```

example output:

```
C:\test>dir *.pdf
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is C8D0-DF1E

 Directory of C:\test

19/06/2015  18:13                 0 A-03.pdf
19/06/2015  17:56                 0 AAAAAAA-01.pdf
19/06/2015  18:14                 0 AB-00.pdf
19/06/2015  18:13                 0 ABCD-01.pdf
19/06/2015  17:56                 0 BBBBBBB-02.pdf
19/06/2015  17:57                 0 CCCCCCC-03.pdf
               6 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  92,870,991,872 bytes free

C:\test>test

C:\test>type c:\list.xls
A
AAAAAAA
AB
ABCD
BBBBBBB
CCCCCCC

C:\test>
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - extract part of a variable (substring)
- [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: Answer updated to answer second part of question.

Comment: @Chaunghian the other answer is better as my two batch files don't work if there is more than 7 characters before the `-` :(. If you don't mind more than 8 characters then the scond part of my answer is shorter than the other one. ;)

Comment: second part of your answer created a space at the end of each file name. Any idea how to get rid of that?

Comment: remove the space before `>>` like `echo %%i>> c:\list.xls`

Comment: thanks David, I export the list as .txt then it's fine. However, export it to .xls then it has the space at the end. Thanks for your help.